# How to add a codecogs equation button to aloha editor toolbar?

Tags: javascript, button, plugins, customization, aloha-editor

I have the aloha editor installed and working. Now I want to create a custom button in the toolbar. That when clicked it opens the [codecogs equation editor popup](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/install.php).
The way I would do it normally without aloha is to add the popup script and call this function

```
<p><a href="javascript:OpenLatexEditor('target','html','')"> 
     Launch CodeCogs Equation Editor</a></p>
```

But I would rather have a button in the toolbar then a link after each editable. I read the plugin documentation for aloha-editor.

This is what I have so far:

```
define([
    'aloha',
    'jquery',
    'aloha/plugin',
    'ui/ui',
    'ui/button'

], function(Aloha,
        jQuery,
        Plugin,
        Ui,
        Button) {
'use strict';

var GENTICS = window.GENTICS;
return Plugin.create('equationButton', {
    init: function () {
       var that = this;

        this._insertEquation = Ui.adopt("insertEquation", Button, {
            iconOnly: true,
            icon: 'aloha-icon-equation',
            click: function(){
                that.insertEQ();
            }
        });
    },
    insertEQ: function() {
        var self = this;

        if(Aloha.activeEditable) {
            window.location = OpenLatexEditor('target','html','');
        }
    }
});
});
```

However, How do I include the script for the equation editor popup which is [here](http://latex.codecogs.com/editor3.js). And is this how I am supposed to use Window.location or does it only take raw url strings?

Thanks,
Jiyda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking in the aloha editor's forum I received my answer from one of the employees and it worked, here is the answer:

Have look at the [metaview plugin](https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/blob/dev/src/plugins/extra/metaview/lib/metaview-plugin.js) -- this is a quite small / simple plugin. There's the "buttonClick" method where you can add the code that should be executed when a button is clicked.
You can copy the metaview plugin, rename it and adjust the rest to you needs.
Be sure to add / adjust also the toolbar.tab settings.
(I suppose the scope should be in your case: "Aloha.continuoustext" )